# How to find which page loads a control

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I have 3 ASP pages that uses the same control.
This control will have to have some javascript validation logic depending on the page that loads it.

I need to find a way to get the name of the page that loads that control.

How can I do it?

I do not have any code yet to post before I decide on the approach, sorry.

Comment: will reading the url from javascript help you?

Comment: I need to find the name of the page that contains the control, so this way I will know what to do. If I were doing it through code behind, I could set up  a public property and then assign a name to it when declaring control on the page. Since, I have to do another way, I will need to use a different approach to find the name of the page

Answer (score 0):

I hope I have understood your question. I do a similar thing to what I believe you are trying to achieve. I name each asppage name NOT the submit page name

e.g. `aspPageName = "page1"`
then store the page name as hidden input field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="aspPageName" value="<%=aspPageName%>" >

<form onsubmit="return validForm()" name="standard" method="post" action="scriptname.asp">
```

then when JS call, set variable in JS pageName

Note: the `<form>` page name can be standard which means all your JS modules can be shared.

I hope I have explained this well enough. Let me know if you need further detail / clarification.

Comment: eugene.it - does this suggestion help you or answer your question?

Answer (score -1):

Well because you weren't too clear I am assuming you just want to read

`window.location.href` or
`window.location.pathname` or one of the `window.location` vars